# Can't find reference to Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, testing

The question is pretty much in the title. I can't find any reference to the Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting library.

I'm using visual studio 2010 ultimate

What's up?

Comment: Sorry got it... I didn't search long enough.
The famework changed name for Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTestFramework

Comment: Post that comment as an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry got it... I didn't search long enough. The famework changed name for Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTestFramework

*as of visual studio 2010 I think.